# What is the type of the index of an array using a range as its index?

Tags: ada

Given the following array definition:

```
type A is array (1 .. 10) of INTEGER;
```

And the following generic:

```
generic
   type LENGTH_T is range <>;
   type INDEX_T is (<>);
   type ELEMENT_T is limited private;
   type ARRAY_T is array (INDEX_T) of ELEMENT_T;
function LIST_IMAGE
  (LENGTH : in LENGTH_T;
   ITEMS  : in ARRAY_T)
   return STRING;
```

Is there a way to instantiate `LIST_IMAGE` for `A`? What do I need to put for the type of the index?

```
function ARRAY_IMAGE is new LIST_IMAGE
  (LENGTH_T  => NATURAL,
   INDEX_T   => ???,
   ELEMENT_T => INTEGER,
   ARRAY_T   => A);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is that an anonymous integer range always becomes an `Integer` subtype:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Range_Of_Universal_Integer is

   type A is array (1 .. 10) of Integer;

   generic
      type Length_T is range <>;
      type Index_T is (<>);
      type Element_T is limited private;
      type Array_T is array (Index_T) of Element_T;
   function List_Image (Length : in Length_T;
                        Items  : in Array_T) return String;

   function List_Image (Length : in Length_T;
                        Items  : in Array_T) return String is
      pragma Unreferenced (Length, Items);
   begin
      return "Hello";
   end List_Image;

   subtype A_Lengths is Integer range 0 .. A'Length;
   subtype A_Range   is Integer range A'Range;

   function Image is
     new List_Image (Length_T  => A_Lengths,
                     Index_T   => A_Range,
                     Element_T => Integer,
                     Array_T   => A);

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Image (Length => 0,
                                Items  => A'(others => 0)));
end Range_Of_Universal_Integer;
```

Comment: Thanks. I previously tried `Integer` instead of `A_Range` but I didn't realize that I am simply missing the range constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Jacob already gave a full answer, but wanted to add an alternative subtype declaration:

```ada
type A is array (1 .. 10) of Integer;

subtype A_Lengths is Integer range 0 .. A'Length;
subtype A_Range   is Integer range A'Range;

function Image is
     new List_Image (Length_T  => A_Lengths,
                     Index_T   => A_Range,
                     Element_T => Integer,
                     Array_T   => A);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one is only correct because `A'Range` happens to start at 1.  If you want to derive `A_Lengths` from `A`, you have to do it like this: `subtype A_Lengths is Integer   range A'First - 1 .. A'Last;`

Comment: I like the idea of your subtype definitions for `A_Length` and `A_Range`.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen Why is the subtype definition for `A_Length` not correct? `A_Range` is not related to `A_Length` after all.

Comment: Sorry.  I misread the meaning of the types.  @Jere is correct in his formulation.  I should correct my example.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your problem by creating a named subtype for your array index.

```
subtype Index_Type is Integer range 1..10;
type A is array(Index_Type) of Integer;

function Array_Image is new List_Image 
  ( Length_T  => Natural,
    Index_T   => Index_Type,
    Element_T => Integer,
    Array_T   => A);
```

Comment: Thanks. Would have done that if I would be able to modify the definition of A, but unfortunately I can't.